# Taking a VmWare Player snapshot

Tags: vmware-player, snapshot

Just wondering, can you take a snapshot from a free VMWare Player Virtual Machine (VM)?

Or is it just for the commercial versions

Comment: I correct your question to use the correct technical words.  Its not a "server" its a Virtual Machine.  It's `VMWare Player` not whatever you had.

Answer (score 4):

No.

> VMware Workstation Pro is much more advanced and comes with powerful features including **snapshots** (...)

From [FAQ](https://www.vmware.com/products/player/faqs.html) ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558915/3109484))

But, you could just pause the VM and copy the VM folder ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20591419/3109484))

Comment: Ok. Many thanks for the information, did not think of that copying.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Tool "VM Snapshot Manager" for exactly that purpose, which you can get from here:
https://github.com/BOfH85/VM_Snapshot_Manager/tree/en-us

It's a terminal based python program which uses 7zip to high-compress your current VMDK-File (or VDI-File since you also can use it with Virtual Box).
It basically copies and compresses your vmdk-harddrive and can restore the compressed files so that you can jump back and forward to any backuped state you created in the past.

It's necessarry for the program to work that you store your VM in only one vmdk-File and don't split it up in several files.

Maybe this tool is helpfull - if so just spread the news, it's free :-)

Regards

BOfH85